# sent files to ftp server use multi thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, rx-java2, ftp-client

I try sent files array to ftp server. I want to do this using multiple threads.

```
Observable oDocType = Observable.create((Observable.OnSubscribe<File[]>) subscriber -> {
        try {
            iRepository.initRepository(userId); // initialization ftp repository
            subscriber.onNext(files);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    })
            .flatMap(Observable::from)
            .flatMap(file -> Observable.create(subscriber -> {
                try {
                    iRepository.save(file);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    oDocType.subscribe(new Action1() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object o) {

        }
    });
```

This code my FtpRepositoriesUserPhoto class.

```
@Override
public void save(File transferObj) throws Exception {
    Boolean status;
    if(!transferObj.exists()) throw new Exception(context.getString(R.string.file_not_found));
    BufferedInputStream buffIn = null;
    buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(transferObj), AppGlobal.BUFFER_SIZE);
    status = mFTPClient.storeFile(transferObj.getName(), buffIn);
    buffIn.close();
    if (!status) throw new Exception(context.getString(R.string.file_not_upload));
}

@Override
public void initRepository(int user) throws IOException {
    mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
    mFTPClient.setConnectTimeout(AppGlobal.FTP_TIMEOUT);
    mFTPClient.connect(AppGlobal.GetIpServer(context), AppGlobal.FTP_PORT);
    mFTPClient.login(AppGlobal.FTP_USER, AppGlobal.FTP_PASSWORD);
    mFTPClient.setBufferSize(AppGlobal.BUFFER_SIZE);
    mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    String UserFolder = String.format("%03d", 119);
    mFTPClient.changeWorkingDirectory(AppGlobal.FTP_DIRECTORY);
    boolean status = mFTPClient.changeWorkingDirectory(UserFolder);
    if (!status){
        status = mFTPClient.makeDirectory(UserFolder);
        if (status){
            mFTPClient.changeWorkingDirectory(UserFolder);
        }
    }
}
```

When sent in different threads, exception occurs

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
10-23 17:48:52.560 22526-22811/ru.app.sale W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
10-23 17:48:52.560 22526-22811/ru.app.sale W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:334)
10-23 17:48:52.560 22526-22811/ru.app.sale W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
```

If sending execute in single thread all files saved in server.
I need to do this in different threads.

Comment: is it `mFTPClient.connect()` statement throwing this exception?

Comment: Why do you want to use multiple threads to send files to the same server? Are you sure this is going to save you time?

Comment: I not know. I want to check this.

Comment: Throwing this exception in statement `status = mFTPClient.storeFile(transferObj.getName(), buffIn);`